# sum column above/below current row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to achieve this in pandas:

```
df['X'] = df['C'].where(row is <= current row).sum()
df['Y'] = df['C'].where(row is >= current row).sum()
```

What is the right syntax to make pandas sum the data from column C that are above or equal to the current row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is cumsum:

```
df['X'] = df['C'].cumsum()
df['Y'] = df['C'].sum() + df['C'] - df['X']
# or 
# df['Y'] = df.iloc[::-1].cumsum()
```

Comment: very needed question and answer

Comment: follow up question: if I need to exclude the current row itself (aka, "row <" vs "row <="), is there an easy way to make `cumsum` do that?

Comment: @Brannon cumsum won't do, but combined with shift does: `df['C'].shift().cumsum()`.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try with `expanding` you can chose the agg function you need etc, `mean`/`std`

```
df['X'] = df['C'].expanding().sum()
df['Y'] = df['C'].iloc[::-1].expanding().sum()
```